# How do I get pygame 1.9.3 to work with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: python, pygame

I am fairly new to Python and pygame as well as Visual Studio. I have managed to get Python 3.6 installed and pygame 1.9.3 and it works as long as I use it in IDLE but when I go to try to use Visual Studio 2017, it does not seem to find pygame.

I have Python and pygame installed at c:\python

Answer (score 1):

On Visual Studio 2017, you click View >> Other Windows >> Python Environments >> Click Package >> search and install with "pygame"[image]

Comment: Maybe more version 1.9.3

Comment: In my visual studio there is not option called other windows under view

Comment: @BrandonKheang You must modify by: Click item install Visual Studio and run, then you click to choose install Python on Visual Studio and wait ... when done you follow my image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wojRJ.png

Comment: This didn't work for me, however, the I did find a tutorial that did. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTIlwYNhTx4